# Copy figure from python to word

Tags: python, image, pdf, report

I am currently doing a report. All my figures are made on matplotlib. I would like to copy my figures to Word but not using screenshot or by right clicking and copy, because in this case the resolution will be reduced. I have nice charts of PDF as an output. Which is the best manner to place them on a Word document?

Comment: save the charts as png, svg or jpg and upload them in word document

Comment: I would also suggest saving the charts as png and insert in Word document will be the best option. You may use VBA or Python to get it automated though.

Comment: I would like something like the figure 2 in this document. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311714088_EXPERIENCES_IN_DEVELOPING_A_DUAL_POROSITY_MODEL_OF_THE_LEYTE_GEOTHERMAL_PRODUCTION_FIELD

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plt.savefig('foo.png')` to save the image as a png, and then from there you can insert into word

Comment: Dont you think is better to save it as svg?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft Word 2016 forward can directly import SVG. So unless you have people viewing it in legacy applications SVG should work just fine

Comment: Look the figure 2, of this document https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311714088_EXPERIENCES_IN_DEVELOPING_A_DUAL_POROSITY_MODEL_OF_THE_LEYTE_GEOTHERMAL_PRODUCTION_FIELD, how do you think they made it?

Comment: I think they generated it with some plotting library for python or R and added the svg into LaTeX. Most of the good research papers and reports are written in LaTeX as opposed to word or google docs. you can check out [sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/) for an online latex creator. But yeah, plt.savefig('foo.svg') should work

Answer (score 0):

Best way I can come up with is this:  save the plot to a file and then add it to your word file. Instead of calling `plt.show()`, you can write `plt.savefig("filename.png")`. This will save the plot as an image to your working directory.